# Fitting a ordinal logistic mixed effect model

Tags: r, logistic-regression, mixed-models, multinomial

How do I fit a ordinal (3 levels), logistic mixed effect model, in R? I guess it would be like a glmer except with three outcome levels.

data structure

```
patientid    Viral_load     Adherence     audit_score     visit
1520         0              optimal       nonhazardous       1
1520         0              optimal       nonhazardous       2
1520         0              optimal       hazardous          3
1526         1              suboptimal    hazardous          1
1526         0              optimal       hazardous          2
1526         0              optimal       hazardous          3
1568         2              suboptimal    hazardous          1
1568         2              suboptimal    nonhazardous       2
1568         2              suboptimal    nonhazardous       3
```

Where viral load (outcome of interest) consists of three levels (0,1,2), adherence - optimal/suboptimal , audit score nonhazardous/hazardous, and 3 visits.

So an example of how the model should look using a generalized mixed effect model code.

```
library (lme4)
test <- glmer(viral_load ~ audit_score + adherence + (1|patientid) + (1|visit), data = df,family = binomial)
summary (test)
```

The results from this code is incorrect because it takes viral_load a binomial outcome.

I hope my question is clear.

Comment: search here and elsewhere for `multinomial (logit/logistic) model`

Comment: You pretty clearly have an ordinal response. There are ordinal/logistic models, so you might incorporate that into the searching efforts.

Answer (score 5):

You might try the `ordinal` package’s `clmm` function:

```
 fmm1 <- clmm(rating ~ temp + contact + (1|judge), data = wine) 

summary(fmm1)   
Cumulative Link Mixed Model fitted with the Laplace approximation

formula: rating ~ temp + contact + (1 | judge)
data:    wine

 link  threshold nobs logLik AIC    niter    max.grad cond.H 
 logit flexible  72   -81.57 177.13 332(999) 1.02e-05 2.8e+01

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 judge  (Intercept) 1.279    1.131   
Number of groups:  judge 9 

Coefficients:
           Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
tempwarm     3.0630     0.5954   5.145 2.68e-07 ***
contactyes   1.8349     0.5125   3.580 0.000344 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Threshold coefficients:
    Estimate Std. Error z value
1|2  -1.6237     0.6824  -2.379
2|3   1.5134     0.6038   2.507
3|4   4.2285     0.8090   5.227
4|5   6.0888     0.9725   6.261
```

I'm pretty sure that the link is logistic, since running the same model with the more flexible clmm2 function, where the default link is documented to be logistic, I get the same results.

I suspect you could have left the LHS as integers and gotten interpretable results just with `glmer`.  I know that strategy was acceptable as a “linear test of trend” when using linear regression machinery. You would not be able to estimate separate log odds ratios for each increment.